# Changes via SetEnvironmentVariable do not take effect in library that uses getenv

Tags: c#, environment-variables, pinvoke

I have a simple c# application that is binding to a library compile with mingnu compiler toolset. I can easily call the functions in the library without issue.

However the library calls `getenv` to set itself up this environment variable needs to be set for the library to work correctly so I am using `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` however the library cannot retrieve the value I have set.

Comment: Make sure you set the correct EnvironmentVariableTarget.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes.aspx  I bet if you set it to the Machine level, it should just work

Comment: This might have something to do with Unicode.  The emulation code in a typical CRT that keeps getenv() compatible with the native utf-16 environment can be quite convoluted.  The MSVC one makes a lazy copy for example.  Tough problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getenv` makes a copy of the environment variable block of the process on startup. Any subsequent changes via `SetEnvironmentVariable` will not be reflected in the block of variables used by `getenv`. You will need to PInvoke the `setenv` function to have the adjusted the value reflected in subsequent `putenv` calls.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec(VS.71).aspx

> getenv and _putenv use the copy of the environment pointed to by the global variable _environ to access the environment. getenv operates only on the data structures accessible to the run-time library and not on the environment "segment" created for the process by the operating system. Therefore, programs that use the envp argument to main or wmain may retrieve invalid information.

Answer (score 3):

You can import the _putenv_s function into your C# class to set the environment variable in a way that will be visible to native C++ code.

This uses `InteropServices`:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class TestEnv
{
    [DllImport( "msvcrt.dll" )]
    public static extern int _putenv_s( string e, string v );

    public TestEnv()
    {
        _putenv_s( "ENV_VAR", "VALUE" );
    }
}
```

There is a tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that may be helpful.

Comment: If the native code has been compiled with Visual Studio 2015 you may have to do it like this:

[DllImport("UCRTBASE.DLL", EntryPoint = "_putenv_s")]
public static extern int _putenv_s_14(string e, string v);

...

_putenv_s_14( "ENV_VAR", "VALUE" );

Answer (score 0):

You just set environment variable after create a native C++ object, then the C++ can get the value of environment variable using getenv function or ACE_OS::getenv().