# SetEnvironmentVariable not working

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need to set two environmental variables (when my application runs) for included 3rd party libraries.

The problem is that 'that way' it is not working, however 
when I run console application, set these two variables and then run the application, everything is okay ...

how to configure these two vars correctly?

i use the procedure:

```
function SetEnvVarValue(const VarName,
  VarValue: string): Integer;
begin
  // Simply call API function
  if SetEnvironmentVariable(PChar(VarName),
    PChar(VarValue)) then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := GetLastError;
end;
```

It returns 0

Maybe the thing is, that i have the libraries being loaded on application startup.
When my application stars I set then the variables and I do it too late ...?

---

Further information

I have included two units in dpr:

ImageMagick in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Lib\Magick\magick\ImageMagick.pas',
magick_wand in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Lib\Magick\wand\magick_wand.pas';

And the Unit:

```
unit DoItFirst;

interface

uses
  Windows, Sysutils;

var
  s: string;
  error: Integer;

function _putenv_s(const lpName, lpValue: PChar): BOOL; cdecl; external 'msvcrt.dll';

implementation

function GetEnvVarValue(const VarName: string): string;
var
  BufSize: Integer;  // buffer size required for value
begin
  // Get required buffer size (inc. terminal #0)
  BufSize := GetEnvironmentVariable(PChar(VarName), nil, 0);
  if BufSize > 0 then
  begin
    // Read env var value into result string
    SetLength(Result, BufSize - 1);
    GetEnvironmentVariable(PChar(VarName),
      PChar(Result), BufSize);
  end
  else
    // No such environment variable
    Result := '';
end;  

initialization

_putenv_s(PChar('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'), PChar('g:\_projekty\ZBar Test\'));
_putenv_s(PChar('MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH'), PChar('g:\_projekty\ZBar Test\modules\coders\'));

s := GetEnvVarValue('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH');
s := GetEnvVarValue('MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH');

end.
```

This unit is at the beginning of dpr file.

Comment: SetEnvironmentVariable returns a Windows error code on failure that you can get through GetLastError. What's the value you get?

Comment: It returns 0 on return

Comment: @John, sounds like the best time to return it, on return :-)

Comment: Third-party libs in your code? Have you considered the possibility they've already _read_ the environment variables before you change them?

Comment: Shit, that is probably the problem ...

Comment: You can test whether or not `SetEnvironmentVariable` works, which it does, by reading the variables after you have set them.

Comment: Yep, I read it. had been set correctly.

Comment: The question title is misleading then. I thought that you were claiming "SetEnvironmentVariable not working". I guess if you want more help, you'll need to let us know how and when these variables are read. We know nothing about these third party libraries, but you do.

Comment: I have edited the original question and gave further information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can discern from your update, the third party library in question is ImageMagick. And the .pas wrappers for that library use load-time linking to the ImageMagick DLL.

When you modify the environment variables from a command interpreter, and then start your process, the ImageMagick DLL can see those environment variables. When you modify the environment variables in your process startup code, the the ImageMagick DLL cannot see those environment variables. Presumably because it has read the variables before your code modifies them.

What I would conclude from the above is that the ImageMagick DLL is reading the environment variables in its initialization.

Because you are using load-time linking, the DLL initialization happens before you have any opportunity to execute your code. I can think of the following ways to work around the issue:

1. Switch from load-time linking to run-time linking for the ImageMagick DLL. This will require you to modify the ImageMagick wrappers that you use. If you are unfamiliar with how to do this, then you might consult the JEDI source code for inspiration. Note that if you are using a modern Delphi, then you can simply modify the wrapper DLL to delay load the ImageMagick DLL. Add the `delayed` directive to the function declarations. This results in run time linking.
2. Move some of your code into a DLL so that you can load it with run-time linking. I'm imagining that you move any code that uses the ImageMagick wrapper into a DLL. That would allow you to keep on using the same wrapper, but still have the ImageMagick DLL loaded at process run-time rather than process load-time. You might even move your entire code into a DLL and then have an executable that did nothing more than load that DLL, and then call a single exported `main` function.
3. Use a separate launcher process. The launcher process prepares the environment, and then launches the real application.

Of these options, the first is by far the most preferable, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank You. I can see your point. I assume I can do that way: set the variables, loadlibrary and invoke method. however I am curious why, when these libs get called so that i cannot set variables earlier ...

Comment: You need to understand the difference between load time linking and run time linking. Read about it on MSDN. The point is that the DllMain function for load time linked DLLs executes before any of your executable's code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is it worth adding that anyone reading this using Delphi 2010 or later has the option of adding the delayed keyword to the dll API declaration which will automatically delay the dll load until the first dll API call fixing the problem without any major rework.  Its obviously not relevant to the current poster as we can see that Delphi 2007 is being used

Comment: @Kanitatlan That's true, I'll do that

Answer (score 4):

You may be changing the environment variables *after* they've been read by the third party libraries.

First up, you should set the environment variable as the first thing tour program does.

Even then, it may be that the third-party libraries could be reading that information in initialisation functions, possibly before your code even starts running.

If that's the case, I *think* the order of initialisation is deterministic (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925472/add-code-before-initialization-of-units-in-delphi)), depending on the order of your units in the `dpr` (project file).

If you want those variables set before the third-party libs look at them, you can create a `DoMeFirst` unit and do it in that unit's init code. Then make sure that's the first one in the project file.

If that doesn't work, another option may be to write a program which changes the environment and *then* calls your current program as a child.

Comment: Is it possible to run the code somewhere in the application before app loads external libraries? i tried to run the code after begin in dpr project but with no luck

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. I did as you proposed. It gets set these two variables at the beginning however still have problem with that libraries :/

Comment: Then your best bet may be to contact the authors of those libraries. BTW, are you sure you have the correct order in the DPR file?

Comment: I found something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788398/changes-via-setenvironmentvariable-do-not-take-effect-in-library-that-uses-geten Maybe that is the problem?